# KNN used to create new synthetic examples in oversampling

Tags: r

i am working with r language and on umbalanced dataset and i need to know how can get the k nearest neighbors of a dataset becaue i need them to create new synthetic examples .

```
   set.seed(123) 
    test <- 1:100
    train.gc <- gc.subset[-test,]
    test.gc <- gc.subset[test,]

    train.def <- gc$Default[-test]
    test.def <- gc$Default[test]

    library(class)
    knn.5 <-  knn(train.gc, test.gc, train.def, k=5)
    #how can i get the five nearest neighbours????????
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example with sample data that we can run please? We don't have your data.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't seem to be documented, the help for `knn` hints that the attributes may store something:

```
 train <- rbind(iris3[1:25,,1], iris3[1:25,,2], iris3[1:25,,3])
 test <- rbind(iris3[26:50,,1], iris3[26:50,,2], iris3[26:50,,3])
 cl <- factor(c(rep("s",25), rep("c",25), rep("v",25)))
 k = knn(train, test, cl, k = 3, prob=TRUE)
 names(attributes(k))
 # [1] "levels"   "class"    "prob"     "nn.index" "nn.dist"
```

and I'd hazard a guess that `nn.index` is the index of the neighbours:

```
> head(attr(k,"nn.index"))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10    2   13
[2,]   24    8   18
[3,]    1   18    8
[4,]    1   18    8
```

I'd guess those are the 3 nearest neighbours of the first four data points.

Comment: I don't get nn.index or nn.dist from `class::knn`

Comment: oh you're using `FNN::knn`

Comment: Oops. But does that answer you question? Is the answer "use FNN::knn to get the nearest neighbours"?